# OpenMP Parallelized Code Runs Slower

Tags: c++, c, openmp

I've seen quite a few posts like this and despite doing quite a bit of reading I can't seem get the following bit of code to parallelize properly in OpenMP, as the serial version currently runs much faster than this:

```
static double red_black_parallel_for_step(simulation* simObj, double stepSize, double* red, double* black){
double tmp = 0.0;   
double avg = 0.0;
double old = 0.0;
double max = -HUGE_VAL;
#pragma omp parallel \
shared(black, red, max) \
firstprivate(old, avg, tmp) 
{
    double priv_max = -HUGE_VAL;
    #pragma omp for 
    for(unsigned int j = 0; j < (*simObj).NY+2; j++){
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < (int)floor((double)((*simObj).NX+2.0)/2.0); i++){
            for(unsigned int k = 1; k < (*simObj).NZ; k++){
                if(red[IX3] == HUGE_VAL) continue;
                old = red[IX3];
                avg = 0.0;
                const int x1 = ( black[IX3+IX3_XR1STEP] != HUGE_VAL ); 
                const int x2 = ( black[IX3+IX3_XR2STEP] != HUGE_VAL ); 
                const int y1 = ( black[IX3+IX3_YSTEP]   != HUGE_VAL ); 
                const int y2 = ( black[IX3-IX3_YSTEP]   != HUGE_VAL ); 
                const int z1 = ( black[IX3+IX3_ZSTEP]   != HUGE_VAL );
                const int z2 = ( black[IX3-IX3_ZSTEP]   != HUGE_VAL );
                if (x1) avg += black[IX3+IX3_XR1STEP];
                if (x2) avg += black[IX3+IX3_XR2STEP];
                if (y1) avg += black[IX3+IX3_YSTEP];
                if (y2) avg += black[IX3-IX3_YSTEP];
                if (z1) avg += black[IX3+IX3_ZSTEP];
                if (z2) avg += black[IX3-IX3_ZSTEP];
                avg /= (double) (x1+x2+y1+y2+z1+z2);
                red[IX3] = old + stepSize * (avg - old);
                tmp = fabs(old - red[IX3]) / fabs(old);
                if( tmp > priv_max ) priv_max = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    #pragma omp flush (max)
    if ( priv_max > max ) {
        #pragma omp critical
        {
            if ( priv_max > max ) max = priv_max;
        }
    }
}
#pragma omp parallel \
shared(black, red, max) \
firstprivate(old, avg, tmp) 
{
    double priv_max = -HUGE_VAL;
    #pragma omp for 
    for(unsigned int j = 0; j < (*simObj).NY+2; j++){
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < (int)floor((double)((*simObj).NX+2)/2.0); i++){
            for (unsigned int k = 1; k < (*simObj).NZ; k++ ){   
                if ( black[IX3] == HUGE_VAL ) continue;
                old = black[IX3];
                avg = 0.0;
                const int x1 = ( red[IX3+IX3_XB1STEP] != HUGE_VAL ); 
                const int x2 = ( red[IX3+IX3_XB2STEP] != HUGE_VAL ); 
                const int y1 = ( red[IX3+IX3_YSTEP]   != HUGE_VAL ); 
                const int y2 = ( red[IX3-IX3_YSTEP]   != HUGE_VAL ); 
                const int z1 = ( red[IX3+IX3_ZSTEP]   != HUGE_VAL );
                const int z2 = ( red[IX3-IX3_ZSTEP]   != HUGE_VAL );
                if (x1) avg += red[IX3+IX3_XB1STEP];
                if (x2) avg += red[IX3+IX3_XB2STEP];
                if (y1) avg += red[IX3+IX3_YSTEP];
                if (y2) avg += red[IX3-IX3_YSTEP];
                if (z1) avg += red[IX3+IX3_ZSTEP];
                if (z2) avg += red[IX3-IX3_ZSTEP];
                avg /= (double) (x1+x2+y1+y2+z1+z2);
                black[IX3] = old + stepSize * (avg - old);
                tmp = fabs(old - black[IX3]) / fabs(old); 
                if( tmp > priv_max ) priv_max = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    #pragma omp flush (max)
    if ( priv_max > max ) {
        #pragma omp critical
        {
            if ( priv_max > max ) max = priv_max;
        }
    }
}
return max;
}
```

The complicating factor is that I need to keep track of the largest relative change (max) between red/black iterations. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Without reading your code the problem your prolly having is that when working on multi processors you have to copy data to different places, many times that will outweigh the gain of parallelization

Comment: I would just save the value of `priv_max` separately for all iterations, then at the very end find the maximum of those values. IF you have so many iterations that you still need/want to do that in parallel, you'll want to do it in a few steps -- e.g., break the array of `priv_max` values into N pieces. Find the maximum of each piece in parallel, then find the maximum of those N serially. For `N` you'll probably want to call `omp_get_max_threads()`.

Comment: Thanks @JerryCoffin. As you can see, each thread has it's own version of priv_max and after the last (outer) loop these are reconciled to choose the largest, to which max is assigned. At only 7 calls to this function, the parallel version takes about 45 seconds and serially runs in 17 seconds. The total number of loop iterations is on the order of 10^7. I don't think that the added bit to reconcile the different priv_max can account for this.

Comment: @Ryan: Sorry -- didn't read the code as carefully as I probably should have. Looking again, about the only advice I can give is to post an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) to allow experimenting with the code.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Ok, I can work on an sscce. In the mean time, I wonder if the continue statement poses problems for OpenMP?

Comment: @JerryCoffin: After checking in to this, as I'm currently using gcc-4.4 (and therefore OpenMP 3.0) it appears that a continue in the innermost loop should be OK (from http://openmp.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=458).

Comment: I don't see where IX3 is defined.  Maybe you have a race condition when you write to `red[IX3]`and/or `black[IX3]`?

Answer (score 0):

Try flushing only after the comparison, and only within the critical block:

```
/* not here: #pragma omp flush (max) */
if ( priv_max > max ) { // this should filter out most of the flush operations
    #pragma omp critical
    {
        if ( priv_max > max ) max = priv_max; // now flush; this operation will be exclusive/"critical"
        #pragma omp flush (max)
    }
}
```